# How to play video from aws

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jsx

I am making a small video gallary with video player in React.
The problem is that when I play a simple http video in my `video tag` it plays fine, but when I use some some  aws url with https, it just gets stuck and doesn't play anything.
Should there be a different approach to play from aws https unlike other link?
Here is the code. This one works great, but link from aws does not. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the aws link as it belongs to company which I am working in.

```html
<video style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} controls>
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videosbucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" 
        type="video/mp4" 
    />
</video>
```

Comment: You need to generate pre-signed URLs for S3 or better: use something like cloudfront.

Comment: thank you, but all the  action  should be done only with aws?

Comment: So? S3 you already mentioned and cloudfront is just another aws service.